# Alphanumeric sorting in spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark

My input will be

```
Id txtyp
1  1
2.  A1
3. A2
4. A3
```

Output should be

```
Id tx_typ
2.  A1
3. A2
4. A3
1. 1
```

I tried with order by() and sort  in spark java but it's not working..any other way or any custom sorting in spark java?

Comment: `Comparator.comparing(s -> s.replaceFirst("^\\d", "z$0"))`

Answer (score 0):

**You can create a new boolean column `is_numeric` which value is `true` when `tx_typ` is numeric else `false`. Then, you sort by the two columns `is_numeric` and `tx_typ`. Finally, you remove `is_numeric` column**.

Translated to code, where `input` is your input `Dataset<Row>` it gives you:

```java
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;

...

input.withColumn("is_numeric", col("tx_typ").cast("int").isNotNull())
  .orderBy("is_numeric", "tx_typ")
  .drop("is_numeric");
```

With following `input` dataset of rows:

```
+---+------+
|Id |tx_typ|
+---+------+
|1  |1     |
|2  |A1    |
|3  |A2    |
|4  |A3    |
+---+------+
```

You get the following output dataset of rows:

```
+---+------+
|Id |tx_typ|
+---+------+
|2  |A1    |
|3  |A2    |
|4  |A3    |
|1  |1     |
+---+------+
```